# Is it possible to show error in error page for "ASP.NET Core app failed to start"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis

A lot of times when your ASP.NET Core application does not start, you see this page:

[image]

This page is different from `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();`.

And debugging this page is hard and sometimes tricky.

Is it possible to somehow get the underlying exception that causes this error and show it in this page?

For example, an instance that this page might be shown is that a DLL is not found. It would be awesome if we could catch that exception and show an `<h1>` at the bottom

> `DLL not found. DLL name: Something.dll`

Comment: What's the first bullet point under "Troubleshooting steps"? No IIS can't show the actual error because the app failed to start.

Comment: Maybe write to the logs, e.g. file, database or something like that.

Comment: @gunr2171, one troubleshooting step is to run the project and wait for the runtime to show the exception. When runtime can show the exception, this means that we **DO** have access to the actual error. The only question remains is how to get it and show it.

Comment: @Julian, we log it. That's a possibility. But it would be much easier to have it in that page. Sometimes the log infrastructure has its own issues and to be able to read log or to access log is not that easy.

Comment: It is not possible unless you roll out your own ASP.NET Core module instead of Microsoft's, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-6.0 The source code is open source though, so anyone with enough experience can give that a try.